# $a$ and $b$ are factors of $6^6$ and $a$ is a factor of $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, factoring

How many pairs of ($a$,$b$) of positive integers are there such that $a$ and $b$ are factors of $6^6$ and $a$ is a factor of $b$?

What I tried

I know $6^6$ an be broken down into $(2)^6 (3)^6$

If $a$ is a factor of $b$,and if $a=1$,there will be $18$ groups.

Since $a$ cannot be higher than $n^3$ to be a factor of b,there are another $9$ groups.

So,total pairs must be $27$ right?

Comment: if $a=1$ then $b$ can be any divisor of $6^6$.  There are $7\times 7=49$ such divisors.

Comment: Why $7 \times 7 =49$?Can explain why do we use $7$?

Comment: Let $b=2^x3^y$.  We have $x,y\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Hence there are $7$ possibilities for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to consider powers of $2,3$ separately.

If $v_2(a)=r$ then $r≤v_2(b)≤6$.  Of course, $v_2(a)\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  If $v_2(a)=0$ there are $7$ possibilities for $v_2(b)$.  If $v_2(a)=1$ there are $6$ possibilities for $v_2(b)$, and so on.  Thus, considering only powers of $2$, we get $$7+6+5+4+3+2+1=\frac {7\times 8}2=28$$ possible pairs.

The same calculation works for the powers of $3$.

As we can sort out powers of $2,3$ independently, we get $$28\times 28 =\fbox {784}$$

Comment: Thanks so much!So I just have to consider the powers separately for the powers of $2$ and $3$ ? Isn't 28 also $\frac {8!}{(6!)(2!)}$,which is from the binomial theorem?How do I use the binomial theorem pascal triangle from that to apply to this?

Comment: Also why $28 \times 28$? Sorry,I'm not really good with combinations.

Comment: There are $28$ possibilities for the "2-part", and $28$ possibilities for the "3-part".  You get to pick one of each.

Comment: In a sense,it's combining the possibilities?

Comment: The way I get $28$ it is a triangular number.  Sum of the integers up to $7$.  True that is a binomial coefficient, but I don't see a quicker way to get to the result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by combining the possibilities.  The 2-part and the 3-part are independent.  You get to choose one with no reference to the other.  That's why it's just a simple multiplication.

Comment: Okay I need some help with the intuition.What do we mean when we times the 28 possible pairs of powers of 2 with the 28 possible pairs of powers of 3.No one really taught me what multiplication really means other than $28 \times 28$ means 28 groups of 28.

Comment: To gain insight, try a smaller example.  That is, you can't realistically list all $784$ cases here.  So try $6^n$ for a smaller $n$ than $6$.  Start with $6^1$.  Then the only pairs are $(a,b)\in \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,6),(2,2),(2,6),(3,3),(3,6),(6,6)\}$  So $9$ cases.  We note that $6^1=2^13^1$ and the relevant triangular number is $2+1=3$ so the answer using my computation was $3\times 3=9$.  Good!  Now you do $6^2$.

Comment: Wait,where is $(1,0),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5)$?

Comment: What are you talking about?  I am listing the pairs $(a,b)$ where both $a,b$ divide $6$ and $a$ divides $b$.  Just like you asked for.

Comment: I think you need to work a lot of examples.  Your text should provide many good exercises.  If not, I find the Art of Problem Solving books and website to be a good source of exercises.  Good luck!  (last comment).

Comment: Thanks.I get it now.I thought the numbers inside the brackets were the powers of 2 and 3...Actually it's factors.Cleared up my misunderstanding!